# Google Static Maps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Static maps, and when I load a page with a unique map for the first time, the image doesn't load. However, if I copy the URL for the image and view it manually in a new tab, the image loads properly from then on.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

I'm linking to an image like this:

```
<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=37.2387556,-76.5096731&markers=size:mid|37.2387556,-76.5096731&zoom=5&size=296x78&sensor=false&key=mykeyhere&maptype=terrain"/>.
```

Comment: What you're doing wrong is not to post some code to help us to better understand your problem

Comment: A small code would be helpful...
Also.. you may find help in https://developers.google.com/maps/support/